# Ruby Shoes doesn't work with symbols

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, shoes

I've installed Shoes at Ubuntu, and it doesn't work correctly.
Example:

it doesn't work

```
     Shoes.app :width => 200 :height => 300 do
    button("Hello"){
        alert("DaBuDi")
    }
end
```

it writes "syntax error" in the Shoes window...

```
 Shoes.app do
    button("Hello"){
        alert("DaBuDi")
    }
end
```

And it works.

I've installed Shoes following the instruction at https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/Building-Shoes-on-Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `,` between hash pairs

```
Shoes.app :width => 200, :height => 300 do
```

maybe it is better to `()`

```
Shoes.app(:width => 200, :height => 300) do
```

Comment: @sooobus Please accept this answer,as it helped you...